# Displaying a DHTML layer over a Silverlight UI

Tags: html, silverlight, dhtml

I have a MOSS 2007 publishing site which incorporates some Silverlight components on various pages.  Beyond a few areas the rest of the site is SharePoint and ASPX (i.e. standard HTML/javascript).

I'm looking at incorporating a dynamic/dropdown menu to the main navigation.  Unfortunately on a few of the pages the menu sits close to a Silverlight area and, when a menu is pulled down it falls "behind" the Silverlight block.

Is there something simple I'm not doing or is there a limitation that Silverlight always be on top of dynamic content displayed via the rest of the HTML DOM?

Any ideas?

-Kevin

Answer (score 2):

In order for Silverlight to appear behind other HTML elements the silverlight plugin needs to run in windowless mode.  You can configure that using a `param` on the `object` tag.

```
          <param name="windowless" value="true" />
```

Note that is can degrade performance and is not recommended if you are displaying video or making heavy use of complex animations.

Comment: +1 this is correct, I had to do this very recently and there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the CSS property: z-index?